# Can one prove non-trivial congruences of triangles without SAS or other congruence axioms?

Tags: geometry, axioms, axiomatic-geometry

In math class, I was told we need to take SAS as an axiom, otherwise we could not prove any congruences besides a triangle and itself. Is that really true? Is there a model of Hilbert's Euclidean geometry axioms (minus SAS and other congruence axioms), where the only way for triangles to be congruent is for them to be the same triangle?

Comment: This seems untrue if you allow yourself ASA, SSS, and/or HL....

Comment: @RiversMcForge No, I am not allowing that either. No congruence axioms.

Comment: OK, then change the question to reflect that. You absolutely can prove non-trivial congruences of triangles without SAS.

Comment: @RiversMcForge: The usual formulation of Hilbert's axioms does not include any triangle congruence axiom besides SAS.

Comment: @EricWofsey As originally worded the question wasn’t about deleting every congruence axiom, just the SAS one. OP also did not specify originally that they were starting from an axiom system where SAS is the only triangle congruence axiom available, and they probably weren’t. But yes, to answer the question that no one was asking, if you only have one triangle congruence axiom, and you take it away, you obviously can’t prove nontrivial triangle congruences any more.

Comment: @RiversMcForge: They explicitly mentioned they were starting from *Hilbert's axioms*, which, as usually formulated, have only one triangle congruence axiom.

Comment: @ericwofsey The original question went beyond “models of Hilbert geometry where no nontrivial triangles are congruent” and asked very specifically if axiom systems of geometry lacking an SAS axiom couldn’t prove **any** nontrivial congruence of triangles: “In math class, I was told we need to take SAS as an axiom, otherwise we could not prove any congruences besides a triangle and itself. Is that really true?“ That is what I addressed in my comment as being false.

Comment: Do we need a triangle congruence axiom to prove nontrivial triangle congruences? Yes, of course. Does it have to be SAS? No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the SAS axiom, there is very little that constrains the congruence relation on angles; it just has to be an equivalence relation that satisfies the "copying an angle" axiom (given any angle, there is a unique congruent angle on a given side of any ray).  So, you could start with the usual model $\mathbb{R}^2$ of Hilbert's axioms (or $\mathbb{R}^3$ if you are doing the 3-dimensional version), and then redefine its angle congruence relation in some nasty way that still satisfies the copying axiom.  For instance, suppose that for each $P\in\mathbb{R}^2$ you specify a bijection $A_P:(0,\pi)\to(0,\pi)$.  Then you could define an angle $\alpha$ at a point $P$ to be congruent to an angle $\beta$ at a point $Q$ iff $A_P(a)=A_Q(b)$, where $a$ and $b$ are the usual radian angle measures of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, respectively.

In particular, by choosing all these bijections $A_P$ one element at a time by a transfinite recursion of length $\mathfrak{c}$, you can arrange that there are no non-equal triangles that are congruent.  At each step where you need to define a new value of some $A_P$, there are fewer than $\mathfrak{c}$ different triangles whose angles you have already specified, and so you can pick a value that avoids repeating any of those angles.  Similarly, at each step where you need to define a new value of some $A_P^{-1}$ (to make sure each $A_P$ is surjective), you can choose it to avoid being equal to the angle measure in any triangle with $P$ as a vertex such that you have already chosen the other two angles.

Comment: So, this answers the question? You proved it?

Comment: Yes, such a model exists.